# Let $G'\triangleleft G$ be a normal subgroup and $K<G$ a subgroup. Is there any relation between $N_{G'}(G'\cap K)$ and $N_{G}(K)$?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G'\triangleleft G$ be a normal subgroup and $K<G$ a subgroup. Is there any relation between the normalizers $N_{G'}(G'\cap K)$ and $N_{G}(K)$?

I'm working with topological groups and I would like to know if $\dim N_{G'}(G\cap K)\leq \dim N_G(K)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: $N_G(K)$ can be finite while $N_{G'}(G'\cap K)$ can be infinite.

Long answer: If $g\in G$ normalizes $K$ then, since $g$ certainly normalizes $G'$, we see that $g$ normalizes their intersection, $G'\cap K$. Thus
$$N_G(G'\cap K)\geq N_G(K).$$
You want something like the other way round. So we have to analyse more.

Notice that if $N\lhd G$ and $N\leq H\leq G$, then $N_G(H)/N=N_{G/N}(H/N)$. Thus to understand $N_G(K)$ we may replace $G$ by $N_G(G'\cap K)$, work modulo $G'\cap K$, and replace $G'$ by some subgroup $X$ such that $G/X$ is abelian. (but $X$ is no longer $G'$). Thus we assume that $X\cap K=1$. Thus $K$ is abelian, and acts on $X$ in the semidirect product $XK$.

But now this gives us a good idea of what to look for. So, in the infinite dihedral group, for example, $G'$ is infinite cyclic, $K$ is the subgroup of order $2$ inverting the cyclic subgroup, and we see that $N_G(K)=K$, while $N_{G'}(G'\cap K)=G'$ is infinite.

For a topological group as an example, choose any simple topological group $X$ and any outer automorphism of order $2$ of $X$, and let $G$ be their semidirect product. Then $G'=X$. In $G$, the normalizer of the outer automorphism $K$ is just its centralizer on $X$, whereas the normalizer of $G'\cap K=1$ is all of $X$.